# 'int' object is not callable error in python when taking cross-entropy of two lists

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

So I am getting an error called `"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"` when I run this code. I did some research and I think it might be due to the fact that the cross entropy variable is declared as a wrong type. I would greatly appreciate some help on figuring out why I'm getting this error. Basically, what I'm doing is taking in two lists and trying to figure out the cross-entropy for the two lists through the code.

```
import numpy as np

# Write a function that takes as input two lists Y, P,
# and returns the float corresponding to their cross-entropy.
def cross_entropy(Y, P):
    Y = np.float_(Y)
    P = np.float_(P)
    crossentropy = 0.0
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        crossentropy+=-1(Y[i]*np.log(P[i]) + (1-Y[i])*np.log(1-P[i]))
    return crossentropy
```

Comment: use `crossentropy += -(...)` without `1` or even uses `-=` like `crossentropy -= (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and computation has several issues beyond the problem you're asking about, but the main issue is this:

```
x = 10
-1(x)
```

This does not work, you need to specific the multiplication, as `-1(x)` in Python means "call `-1` (as a function) with the argument `x`".

I.e.:

```
crossentropy += -1 * (Y[i]*np.log(P[i]) + (1-Y[i])*np.log(1-P[i]))
```

Note that afterwards, you are likely to get warnings about divisions by zero, depending on the inputs of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```py
crossentropy+=-1(Y[i]*np.log(P[i]) + (1-Y[i])*np.log(1-P[i]))
```

has a `1` that is being treated as a function (ie “being called”). Try removing this integer, and the summation should work.